# MySQL - mydumper locking

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm using mydumper to backup my MySQL database, since most other tools a pretty slow compared to this.

Here is my scenario:

1. I'm backing up my database once a week using a cron job.
2. The backup must happen on a live server, no interruption allowed.
3. There are a few small databases that must be backed up consistently, and then 3 large databases with 200,000 tables where consistency is not important (tables is these DBs do not contain any foreign keys and if a few inserts/updates are lost it is not an issue).
4. All databases are InnoDB.

mydumper has the following locking options, but their documentation is not very clear on the implication of each one. Some help is appreciated.

**--no-locks**: Do not execute the temporary shared read lock.  WARNING: This will cause inconsistent backups

**--no-backup-locks**:  Do not use Percona backup locks

**--less-locking**:  Minimize locking time on InnoDB tables

**--lock-all-tables**: Use LOCK TABLE for all, instead of FTWRL

**--trx-consistency-only**: Transactional consistency only

With both --no-backup-locks and --less-locking, locking takes too long. All databases are inaccessible (not just the DB being backed up), for hours while the backup is running. So this is not an option.

--no-locks might lead to inconsistent  backups, so I should probably not go that route.

--lock-all-tables allows me to continue operating in a live environment at first. But after about 15min is also causes mysql to become inaccessible.

How does --trx-consistency-only differ from the other options?

**[EDIT]** For future readers: it seems that --trx-consistency-only works well on InnoDB. Minimal locking and the DB is consistent. No interruption in a live environment.

Comment: How does point 3 (about the 3 large databases) relate to `--no-locks might lead to inconsistent backups, so I should probably *not* go that route.` ?

Comment: @Luuk yeah thought about maybe doing that for the 3 large DBs (and a consistent backup for the smaller DBs). Are there any issues with importing the backup if it is inconsistent? Will mysql complain about anything?

Comment: If you do not have foreign keys, only users can complain, if (and only IF) they notice an inconsistency.

Comment: @goocreations can you reply to this thread with your "EDIT: For future readers" and mark that as the accepted answer? It was helpful for me but it should be marked as an accepted answer so it's not hidden in your question. Thanks!